# android: customized text selector

Tags: android, colors, selector, textview

I wanted to design a customized text selector that changed the text color when user clicks the TextView. But got the following error:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #55: Error inflating class

here is what I have:
 drawable/text_selector.xml

```
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
  <item android:state_enabled="false" 
        android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/black" /> 
  <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" /> 
  <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/black" /> 
</selector>
```

layout/textview.xml

```
<TextView android:id = "@+id/last_page_button"
    android:text="@string/last_page_button_string" 
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:textColor = "@drawable/text_selector"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

values/color.xml

```
<resources> 
    <color name="white">#ffffffff</color> 
    <color name="black">#ff000000</color> 
    <color name="blue">#ffccddff</color>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't assign drawable to textColor. It has to be a Color.

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"

        android:color="@color/color1" />
    <item
        android:color="@color/color2" />
</selector>
```

create a folder color in your res , save this file as mycolor.xml and assign it to textColor as @color/mycolor

Comment: Does it have to be the color folder? Can't I put it under the values folder? I tried it didn't work under values/

Comment: it has to be color . Why would you put it in values ? Also make sure that your view is getting state from the parent.

Comment: thanks, the exception no longer exisits. However, when I "click" the textview, the color doesn't change. I'm wondering if there is a state called pressed? Or is that for button only? What state should I specify when user clicked a textivew?

Comment: @AlexVolovoy Hello While i trying to Apply When user Touch on TextView i use All of Above thing in Code but no Effect At all.i Check this in android 2.1update-1.

Comment: Ok i think in TextView We can not Directly Give textColor as @color/mycolor to make textview to be change TextColor so we can use this Thing in Button View or Like Some in This Example [http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/res/color/bright_text_dark_focused.html]

Comment: The selector has to have all 3 states specified, not only `android:state_selected`, to work. 
As @Herry has specified, this is taken from android sdk samples:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="#fff" />
      <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#fff" />
      <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#fff" />
      <item android:color="#000" />
    </selector>

Comment: Meet same question. DONT FORGET put "android:clickable="true" under your TextView

Answer (score 0):

use selector as follows:

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_selected="true"

    android:color="@color/c1" />
<item
    android:color="@color/c2" />
```